# Как реализовать декоратор, подсчитывающий количество вызовов функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x, шаблоны-проектирования, декоратор

Объясните на примере простого python-кода.
Как мне декорировать функцию, которая подсчитывает количество вызовов функции? При этом, как мне составить правильно и саму инкрементирующую функцию?

```
def f():
    counter = 0
    if (f):
        counter += 1
    return counter
```

Дополнение к вопросу:
Например, разберемся сначала с самой функцией, без декоратора.
Почему у меня в результате выполнения функции, выводится "1" ? Ведь функция вызывалась 3 раза.

```
def f():
    counter = 0
    if (f):
        counter += 1
    return counter

f()
f()
f()

result = f()

print(result)
```

**Замыкание** – это когда вложенная функция может пользоваться переменными, которые объявлены снаружи этой функции.
И, после того, как функция отработает, значение переменной останется в памяти, не будет удалено.
И, при каждом вызове функции, когда мы передаем туда каждый раз разный аргумент, отображается каждый раз разное значение.

**Декоратор** – это функция, которая добавляет новую функциональность к другой функции без изменения её кода. Он как бы оборачивает, декорирует функцию, тем самым расширяя её возможности.
Декоратор – это функция, которая принимает другую функцию и возвращает функцию (замыкание).

Comment: Приведите код декоратора из учебника, который вам непонятен. Напишите, что именно в этом коде вам непонятно. Декораторы описаны много раз и много где, полностью это повторять нет смысла, но можно сосредоточиться на конкретном аспекте, который лично вам непонятен.

Comment: https://www.python-course.eu/python3_decorators.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не, ну можно, конечно, и через декоратор:

```
# Сам декоратор-счётчик

def counter(func):
    
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapper.count += 1
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    
    wrapper.count = 0
    return wrapper


# Функция, вызовы которой нужно считать

@counter
def f():
    print("Hello")


f()
f()
f()

print(f.count)
```

Но всё-таки, это извращение. Если у вас есть некое состояние, которое нужно запоминать и потом к нему обращаться, то самый логичный путь - использовать класс. Как именно - уже написали в другом ответе.

Comment: почему это извращение? функции в пайтон это тоже объект. и мы используем это, так же как и декоратор wraps из модуля functools, который добавляет ссылку на оригинальный метод в аттрибут `__wrapped__`. Так что все вполне нормально.

Comment: Тема декораторы вроде бы тесно связана с темой - замыкания.  Надо мне сейчас понять, есть ли в вашем коде замыкание.  Если да, то зачем оно нужно. И, в целом, тему декораторов еще разобрать нужно. Еще отвечу.

Comment: @alex Ну, возможно, это моё имхо. Но, на мой взгляд, появление у функции публичных аттрибутов, к котором предполагается штатно обращаться - это контринтуитивно и не является хорошей практикой.

Comment: В пятой строчке мы объявляем вложенную функцию def wrapper(*args, **kwargs): и в 10 строчке мы возвращаем эту функцию return wrapper.  Для чего это? Это замыкание?

Comment: По-моему замыкание здесь нужно, чтоб все аргументы и все переменные во внешней ф-ции и вложенной ф-ции  были видны в обоих этих функциях. Ведь суть замыкания: Замыкание – это когда вложенная функция может пользоваться переменными, которые объявлены снаружи этой функции.

Comment: Xander, ваш ответ и есть решение. Почему одинаковые параметры в строке 5 у ф-ции wrapper, и в строке 7 у ф-ции func ? И почему мы пишем не обычную переменную, а через точку wrapper.count ?

Comment: @Muriam 1. Замыкания здесь нет. Замыкание - это когда внутри функции используется переменная, объявленная во внешней области видимости. Это позволяет делать ряд любопытных штук и действительно часто используется в декораторах, но здесь такого нет. 2. Про wrapper: Смысл любого декоратора в том, что он конструирует некоторую обёртку вокруг какой-то функции, и эта обёртка потом притворяется этой самой задекорированной функцией. Именно это тут и происходит.

Comment: @Muriam 3. Про аргументы args и kwargs - чтобы обёртка могла притворятся функцией, которую она декорирует, она должна уметь принимать те же аргументы, что и декорированная функция. Если мы заранее не знаем, какие там будут аргументы, мы можем просто обобщённо указать все позиционные и именованные аргументы. В седьмой строчке они же - потому что обёртка просто как есть передаёт эти аргументы в задекорированную функцию.

Comment: @Muriam 4. Мы используем wrapper.count , потому что обычную переменную нельзя хранить внутри функции и обращаться к ней извне. Т.к. функция является объектом, то так же как и для обычного объекта, мы можем прицепить к ней произвольный аттрибут через точку и использовать его.

Answer (score 3):

Ну и в дополнение ко всему уже изложенному пример класса декортатора.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
#
class Decorator:
    count = 0

    def __init__(self, fun):
        self._fun = fun

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.count += 1
        return self._fun(*args, **kwargs)


@Decorator
def foo(a): ...


foo()
print(foo.count)
```

Answer (score 2):

`counter` - это **локальная переменная** функции `f`, она будет обнуляться каждый раз, когда вы вызываете функцию. Если хотите сохранять значение, напишите класс и используйте переменные либо класса, либо экземпляра класса, чтобы сохранить состояние переменных. Здесь я использую экземпляр класса:

```
class Counter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
    def increment(self):
        self.counter += 1
        return self.counter

cnt = Counter()
cnt.increment()
cnt.increment()
cnt.increment()

result = cnt.increment()

print(result) # 4
```

Для счётчика можно использовать и глобальную переменную `global counter`, так для начинающих обычно проще:

```
def f():
    global counter
    counter += 1
    return counter

counter = 0
f()
f()
f()

result = f()

print(result) # 4
```

Но глобальные переменные "замусоривают" память программы и не очень совместимы с принципами ООП, в общем, их лучше не использовать, а поручить конкретные функции конкретному классу, предназначенному для этих функций. Когда вы правильно используете классы, у вас как бы есть гарантия, что класс меняет только своё внутреннее состояние, а когда вы используете глобальные переменные у вас любая функция может поменять любую глобальную переменную и поэтому очень сложно искать и диагностировать ошибки, выяснять, какая функция и в какой момент поменяла состояние программы.

Что касается декораторов - предлагаю вам конкретизировать вопрос, потому что декораторы описывались и разбирались много раз, если вам что-то непонятно в имеющихся объяснениях, добавьте код в вопрос и обозначьте непонятные для вас места кода. Так же как вы сделали с функцией `f` в вашем вопросе.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения. И у вас всё правильно считается. Подумаю теперь о декораторе и как его применить.

Comment: А чтоб не использовать ООП, можно ли применить глобальную переменную для счетчика?  Раз локальная переменная обнуляется.

Comment: @Muriam Глобальную переменную можно применять, но лучше так не делать по многим причинам. Когда у вас код маленький так ещё можно делать, а когда большой и сложный проект, использование глобальных переменных обязательно приведёт к проблемам.

Comment: это первый мой декоратор в жизни. Не знаю, что еще можно придумать, кроме как взять за основу то, что сделал пользователь Xander. И понять как этот код функционирует.

Comment: От себя добавлю, как понимаю: Декоратор - это ф-ция (counter стр.5), которая принимает другую ф-цию (func стр.5) и возвращает ф-цию (wrapper стр.12). Декоратор - это ф-ция counter, которая необходима для расширения функционала другой ф-ции f

Comment: Также в этом коде есть замыкание.  Это когда вложенная функция (wrapper) может пользоваться переменными, которые объявлены снаружи этой функции (в ф-ции counter).

Comment: CrazyElf, спасибо большое за такое подробное разъяснение. Очень помогло. И за время, потраченное на такое количество текста. Но я не могу выбрать несколько лучших ответов, а только один.

Comment: @Muriam Ну, тема вашего вопроса всё-таки про декораторы (хотя содержание вопроса не только про них), поэтому вы правильно отметили ответ, где объяснили именно про декораторы, там и в комментариях отвечающий постарался, так что всё хорошо )